# New initial condition when changing variables in uniform heat equation

Tags: heat-equation, change-of-variable

I will be very glad of your help if you explain to me what it follows from the equality to zero $\phi = 0$ in the initial condition (highlighted in red in the figure) after the indicated chaching of variables from v to $\phi$?[image: formulation of the heat equation problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v(x,0)=0$ for all $x$, then
$$
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,0) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \Bigl( v(x,0) \Bigr) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \Bigl( 0 \Bigr) =0
$$
for all $x$ too. So
$$
\varphi(x,0) = v(x,0) - \dfrac{1}{h} \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,0) = 0
$$
for all $x$.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation